# How does MvcRazorCompileOnPublish work in a asp.net 2.0 core .csproj file

Tags: razor, msbuild, asp.net-core-2.0

If I reference the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation from nuget then suddenly my razor views are precompiled on publish. However if I specify

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

then they are not.
but HOW is this set up?
I've had a look through the ViewCompilation source ( https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation ) but I cannot see there HOW MvcRazorCompileOnPublish deactivates the view precompilation, I only see examples of it working...

Comment: It's used as part of a condition in the MSBuild tasks. See [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets).

Comment: aha, so am I right in assuming it's kickstarted by line 167? AfterTarget="PrepareForPublish" and the PrepareForPublish target is part of the standard build/publishing pipeline for .net core web projects?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, its like Kirk Larkin said. The secret sauce is in https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets line 167